# OData with multiple keys

Tags: c#, odata

I'm using the Microsoft.OData 6.11.0 package, and I'd like to be able to allow users of the API to use one of three properties (DB primary key, username, or external ID number) as the key for a data type representing people. The formats for the properties are different enough that they can be distinguished between easily. I set up the OData model as follows:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Person>("Person");
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "ODataRoute",
    routePrefix: "OData",
    model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

In the controller, I have:

```
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<Person> Get([FromODataUri] String key) {/*...*/}

[EnableQuery(PageSize = 100)]
public IQueryable<Widget> WidgetsFromPerson([FromODataUri] String key) {/*...*/}
```

which takes a guess at which identifier is provided and returns the appropriate data. These work:

```
GET http://localhost/app/OData/Person(1234)
GET http://localhost/app/OData/Person(999999999)
GET http://localhost/app/OData/Person(1234)/Widgets
GET http://localhost/app/OData/Person(999999999)/Widgets
```

These get me a 404.

```
GET http://localhost/app/OData/Person('username')
GET http://localhost/app/OData/Person('username')/Widgets
```

If I can't do this, is there an alternate syntax I can use to get the person by username as well as the widgets for that person by username?

The metadata returned through the API includes this:

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema Namespace="MyModel" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
      <EntityType Name="AbstractPerson" Abstract="true">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="PersonId" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="PersonId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="Person" BaseType="MyModel.Person">
        <Property Name="UserName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="Widgets" Type="Collection(MyModel.Widget)" />
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think your going to have to specify it in a filter.  How Odata know since your data types with either be int, string, string or int, string, int

Comment: I was hoping that I could just change the parameter type in the OData controller action from int to string. What does the syntax for that filter look like? If it's the $filter syntax, how can I apply that to the person when getting the widgets for that person?

Comment: That's fine but you want to use 3 different fields so 2 of those would overlap Assuming primary key is an int, how could Odata tell between the external ID(string) and the username(string)

Comment: Does OData need to know the difference? The two properties of the same type have different formats: one is a fixed-width number and the other is alphanumeric, so I my controller action basically has `if (Regex.IsMatch("[0-9]{7}", key)) { // use key as external ID string } else if (Int32.TryParse(key, out personId)) { // use personId as DB ID int } else { // use key as username string }`.

I think the reason the external ID works is that it happens to be parsable as an integer, though it really isn't one.

Comment: I tried using two controller actions that varied only in the type of the key parameter, but that gets me `Multiple actions were found that match the request`.

Comment: You could wrap the controller and then parse the regex to determine its route and then forward it to the correct odata controller

Comment: You could probably overload a route with your regex and then it route fine, check here for example http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do think what you're looking for is a feature similar to alternate key.

OData team is working on alternate key supporting. You can find the detail information and sample from [here](https://github.com/OData/vocabularies/blob/master/OData.Community.AlternateKeys.V1.md)

Besides, you can find the [implementation](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/pull/219) in progress.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is in beta on Nuget.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you get from `ODataModelBuilder` to `IEdmEntityType`, the type for which the `AddAlternateKey` extension method is declared. Do you have an insight into that?

Comment: I was wrong about it being in beta anyway. They have the pull request under the 6.13 milestone, but it's not in the beta on nuget. Still, the right answer seems to be "wait".

Comment: is there a way to send an array of keys to request multiple entities?

Comment: @Farzad you can create an Edm function to accomplish that.